# How to save payment through cards on PayPal? PayPal Subscription is not working because payment card is not saving in vault

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, woocommerce-subscriptions

It's enabled here but subscription renewal is not working and when user pay it's set to manual renewal instead automatic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq4yA.png

Answer (score 2):

If using the WooCommerce PayPal Payments plugin, there is [an important note here](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-paypal-payments/#vaulting-saving-a-payment-method):

> **Requirements for automatic payments**
>
> Your PayPal account has to be [approved for Reference Transactions](https://woocommerce.com/document/paypal-reference-transactions/#section-1)
> to save PayPal accounts in the Vault, e.g. for automatic subscription
> renewal payments. Credit cards can be saved in the Vault via Advanced
> Card Processing and used for automatic payments without requiring
> Reference Transactions.

Beyond that, your question needs more information about what you've tried so far and what's not working (for what payment types -- subscribing with PayPal and subscribing with a card are two different things)

Comment: You are right, I tried to enable vault option under paypal app, but Advanced Card Processing is disabled, and i contacted paypal support and they are not replying, they are only one who can enable Advanced Card Processing and reference transactions, i think, or there is any way to enable by own?

Comment: Enable advanced via https://www.paypal.com/bizsignup/ .  Reference transaction is needed for vaulting PayPal account payments, only PayPal's business support (not technical support) can enable that.

Comment: I asked paypal's business support, but they are not responding

Comment: It's not a simple approval, only available for certain businesses. WooCommerce has an FAQ here: https://woocommerce.com/document/paypal-reference-transactions/#section-1

Comment: got it thanks, can you approve my question, so anyone can get help

Comment: WooCommerce FAQ: "Unfortunately, PayPal does not publish these requirements and based on anecdotes from customers, the requirements can be different for different businesses."